# Is there a way to change file names

Tags: javascript, filenames

I have a bunch of photo's with specified names downloaded from an api. 
But instead using there short name I want to rename them to there fullname. 
Is there away to do that with a script I don't want to do it manual because there are to much. Some thing like this maybe?

```
$.each(priceData.result, function (index, item) {
    $.each(allCoinData.result, function (allCoinIndex, allCoinItem) {
        if (allCoinItem.Currency == item.MarketName.substr(4) && item.MarketName.substr(0, 4) == 'BTC-')
change src'assets/media/Bittrex/"+ allCoinItem.Currency +".png' to src'assets/media/Bittrex/"+ allCoinItem.CurrencyLong +".png'
```

Is something possible? 
I can also create an array of the photo's I need to change and an array of the names they need to change in.

Comment: what files ? the ones on the server? the ones you downloaded in the page? the ones your user will download on their disk?

Comment: The ones I downloaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery to get the image by its source and change it:

```
$.each(priceData.result, function (index, item) {
    $.each(allCoinData.result, function (allCoinIndex, allCoinItem) {
        if (allCoinItem.Currency == item.MarketName.substr(4) && item.MarketName.substr(0, 4) == 'BTC-')
            $("img[src='assets/media/Bittrex/"+ allCoinItem.Currency +".png']")
            .attr("src","assets/media/Bittrex/"+ allCoinItem.CurrencyLong +".png");
```

**Edit**

Per request to change the actual file names in windows, given the arrays you said you can make you can use this script.

```
var fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var srcFiles =["fn.js"]; // array of source file names
var destFiles =["fn-out.js"]; // array of source file names
var CurDir = fso.GetFolder(".");
var Files = CurDir.Files;
for(var i=0;i<srcFiles.length;i++)
{
    if (fso.FileExists(srcFiles[i]))
    {
        fso.CopyFile(srcFiles[i],destFiles[i])
    }
}
```

You will need to save that code into a file in the directory the files are in with a `.js` extensions, for example `fn.js`. You will then need to open a windows command prompt in that directory by holding shift and right clicking on white space in that directory and choosing open command window here.

[image: Open command window from windows explorer]

In the command window enter the command `cscript [filename]` where `[filename]` is the name of the file you saved the above script in and hit enter.

For example:

```
cscript fn.js
```

When the program completes, all of the files named in srcFiles will be copied to destFiles.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That will change the name of photo but the realname of photo will stay the same. I want to change the original name is that possible?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you post code of what you are trying to change?

Comment: I want to change the name of the file so I search it in windows I will need to search for allCoinItem.CurrencyLong instead of the allCoinItem.Currrency

Comment: Thank you very much Alexander Higgins you really helped my out!